# Spring Project without annotations in IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDE which by default generates a annotation based SpringApplication when I create a new Project for Spring Application. I want to first learn the concepts of Spring Application without Annotations(XML based). Could anyone give me suggestion for how to set in the IDE such that I get a non-annotation based  project by default when I select for New Project.

The current version of Spring is

```
          3.2.0
```

Comment: You can generete the default annotation base spring application and then remove annotations support from your application context xml and classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a basic annotation based Spring 3.2.0 app here : https://github.com/ajorpheus/hello-spring/

If you are comfortable with Git/Github, then clone that repository locally and import that project into Intellij using `File -> Import Project`  ( otherwise, you could download the zip of the project itself : https://github.com/ajorpheus/hello-spring/archive/master.zip and then go from there. No git-fu needed.)

This project runs fine in Intellij as a maven project.

---

I have taken the liberty of also interpreting your question as 'How to learn Spring'. IMHO, here is what helped me when I was starting out with Spring.

#### First Steps

To start with, for further reading or a bit of experimentation, these seem like a good start :

- http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/#quick-start
- http://spring.io/guides/gs/maven/

#### Books / Resources

I also recall that reading '[Spring In Action - Third Edition](http://www.manning.com/walls4/)' helped when I was starting out with Spring, though I would not recommend buying it now since a much more up-to-date Fourth Edition is on it's way.

A couple of threads here also cover the topic of 'Best Resources for learning Spring' :

1. [Book suggestion for Spring framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115163/book-suggestion-for-spring-framework)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610733/best-way-to-learn-spring-framework

You'll find some books/resources repeatedly being mentioned is threads such as the above. 'Spring Recipes', 'Spring in Action', 'Pro Spring', 'Official Spring Documentation'  ... all of these 'spring' to mind :D.

Finally, as far as Spring is concerned, there is no dearth of resources or threads advising about these resources. I'd recommend not spending a lot of time researching where to start. Just a pick a book which has been mentioned in more than one threads and go for it !

Hope this helps !